# How do I think of closure of a set?

Tags: general-topology

> A closure of a set $S$ in a topological space refers to a set $\tilde{S}$ containing all points of $S$ and limit points of $S$
>
> Limit/Cluster/Accumulation point of a set: A point $p$ in a topological space $X$  is a limit point or cluster point or accumulation point of the set $S$ if every neighborhood of $x$ contains at least one point of $S$ different from $x$ itself.
>
> Neighborhood : Neighborhood  of a point is a set $V$ containing the point inside of which there is an open set $U$ containing that point

Here's what I understand about the three definitions written. I think of the set as sort of powder, and when we put a topology on it, we can think of clumping certain parts together (these clumped parts are open set). A given speck of powder can belong into two different clumps, I understand the limit point definition as a point such that for each clump of dust it belongs to, there is another point in that clump (clump=open set).

I'm not sure how to extend the above idea to understand closure of a set.

Comment: My intuition about the closure of a **set** (note:  *all* topological spaces are closed, hence the closure of a topological space is that space itself) relates to my notions of the limit points, boundaries, and other related topics.  Perhaps you could explain *your* intuitions about the terms you have defined, and let us know where the confusion is.

Comment: Also, I would highly recommend that you spell things out.  For example, write out "neighborhood" where it appears, write "with respect to" rather than "w.r.t.", and so on.  The use of abbreviations increases the cognitive load required to read the question.

Comment: I tried to put my intuition of it. It's on the speculative side, so there is a chance you find that my intuition is totally off @XanderHenderson

Answer (score 4):

This is a matter of opinion, but I would suggest that the fundamental idea of topology is **nearness**.  This is motivated (largely) by a desire to extend notions of limit, continuity, differentiability, etc., to more general spaces.  For example, in $\mathbb{R}$, we might define limits via something like

> **Definition:** Let $f : D \to \mathbb{R}$, where $D \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, and suppose that $L \in \mathbb{R}$.  Say "the limit of $f(x)$ as $x$ approaches $a$ is $L$," and write
> $$ \lim_{x\to a} f(x) = L, $$
> if for any real number $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that for any $x \in D$ which satisfies $0<|x-a| < \delta$, it follows that $|f(x) - L| < \varepsilon$.

Fundamentally, this says "if $x$ is 'near' to $a$, then $f(x)$ is 'near' to $L$."  In $\mathbb{R}$, this notion of "nearness" is relatively natural, as there is a *metric* which allows us to put a number on the "distance" between two points.  One of the goals of topology is to generalize away any specific notion of "nearness", so metrics and distances and inequalities and whatnot are replaced by **open sets**.

Roughly speaking, a *neighborhood* of $x$ is the collection of all points in a space which are "near" to $x$.  *How* near is kind of irrelevant—in a Euclidean space, any open ball centered at $x$ is a neighborhood of $x$; that ball might have a huge radius, and there might be points with seem pretty far away, but those points are still "near" in this technical sense (i.e. they are contained in an open set which also contains the point).

Given an arbitrary set in a topological space, we might want to consider all of the points which are "near" to that set.  One possible way of describing this is to declare that a point is "near" to a set if every neighborhood of that point contains some (other) point of the set—no matter how much we "zoom up on" some point, we will always find points of our set of interest which are "near" to that point.  In more formal language,

> an accumulation point of a set $S$ is a point $p$ such that for any neighborhood $U$ of $p$,
> $$ (U \cap S) \setminus \{p\} \ne \varnothing. $$

The *closure* of a set then consists of all of the points in $S$, along with all of the points which are "near" $S$ (in the sense that they are accumulation points).

Answer (score 2):

You can think of the closure of $S$ as the set obtained by the set itself and its boundary.
An easy example is the following:
Suppose that we are in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and consider the set $S = \{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2: x<1\}$. Then, its closure is the set $\overline{S}=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2: x \leq 1\}$.
Therefore, intuitively, the closure is the set and its border. In your analogy with the powder, it is like surrounding the powder with a string that defines exactly where the powder ends. However, I would suggest you look at more example in $\mathbb{R}^2$, for instance, in order to get a more geometrical intution and visualize it better.